# When I search , Button action in Cell don't work

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift4

In my app, I used [XLPagerTabStrip](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip)! library.

[[HomeViewController like this  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULxk7.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULxk7.png)

In my HomeView controller, I have a 3 child view that uses same searchBar in NavigationController.

In my ChildOneController, I have a tableView that list videos.

I have a button in TableViewCell. When I click this button, pushviewController. But when i searched and click this button push don't work.

here is my code :

```
func joinBtnDelegate(at index: IndexPath) {

        if let jlist = self.joinAllAllowedInnoList , !jlist.isEmpty{
            Dataholder.sharedInstance().selectedJoin = jlist[index.row]
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PickVideoViewController") as! PickVideoViewController
           self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `navigationController` should not be `nil` in below line of code.

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```